# File cannot be opened - however it does exist - swift 3

Tags: swift, file, filesystems, swift3, ios10

I am recording video to a file with this code:

```
print(documentsPath)
            //var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFB207E7-36CC-4C53-A2E2-5FADC7C23A18/Documents/gymnastVideos/test.mp4
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)
        videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath as URL!, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

and have verified that the file exists, however, when I try to open the file to check if anything is being saved there, I return an error.  The code:

```
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        documentsPath.append("/gymnastVideos")
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)

        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: filePath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            print(directoryContents)
            print("!")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
                //The file “gymnastVideos” couldn’t be opened.
            print("!!")
        }
```

Why can't I open the file, and what do I need to change in my code to be able to open the file?

Comment: you forgot to add the file name `/gymnastVideos/test.mp4`

Comment: I'm looking for that file in the directory gymnastVideos - it cannot open the directory gymnastVideos